# Why does xorg.conf produce an incorrect monitor order?

Tags: x11, xorg, configuration, multi-monitor, xrandr

My monitor setup is as follows:

[image]

But everytime I login to any Qtile or KDE the default layout is set to this:

[image]

Even when I explicitly tell the `xorg.conf` to put `HDMI-0` on the left.
Does anyone know why it seems to "not listen" to the configuration or if there is any workaround? I worked around it in KDE by adding a `xrandr` script but this doesn't seem like the right way as my login screen is still not good.

I'm using an Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB.

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`

```
# HP 2211x
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "DVI-D-0" 
    Option "RightOf" "DP-0"
EndSection 

# Dell U2414H
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "HDMI-0" 
    Option "Rotate" "left"
    Option "LeftOf" "DP-0"
EndSection 

# Asus ProArt PA278QV
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "DP-0" 
    Option "Primary" "True"
EndSection
```

I have also tried using `"Position"` but this still produces the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The associations of the video card outputs to the monitors are missing. You need a file with a section like this:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "card0"
  Option "monitor-HDMI1" "monitor2"
  Option "monitor-HDMI2" "monitor0"
  Option "monitor-HDMI3" "monitor1"
EndSection
```

In this example (an old configuration from my system), "card0" is the name of my Intel IGP, "monitor-HDMIX" its outputs and "monitorX" the Identifiers of the monitor sections (in your case "DVI-D-0", "HDMI-0", , "DP-0").

Your `10-monitor.conf` file is absolutely valid, btw.

Here is the complete monitor config from my old system. I hope it will help you to solve your problem:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "monitor0"
  Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1200"
  Option "DPMS" "true"
  Option "Primary" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "monitor1"
  Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
  Option "DPMS" "true"
  Option "LeftOf" "monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "monitor2"
  Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
  Option "DPMS" "true"
  Option "RightOf" "monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier "card0"
  VendorName "Intel"
  BoardName "HD Graphics P4600"
  Driver "intel"
  Option "DRI" "3"
  Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
  Option "TearFree" "true"
  Option "VSync" "true"
  Option "TripleBuffer" "true"
  Option "monitor-HDMI1" "monitor2"
  Option "monitor-HDMI2" "monitor0"
  Option "monitor-HDMI3" "monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "screen0"
  Device "card0"
  Monitor "monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1200"
  EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "screen1"
  Device "card0"
  Monitor "monitor1"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
  EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "screen2"
  Device "card0"
  Monitor "monitor2"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
  EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier "layout0"
  Screen "screen1" LeftOf "screen0"
  Screen "screen0" 
  Screen "screen2" RightOf "screen0"
  Option "BlankTime" "15"
  Option "StandbyTime" "20"
  Option "SuspendTime" "25"
  Option "OffTime" "30"
  Option "DontZoom" "true"
EndSection
```